# Android UI Design tool

Tags: android, designer, ui-design

I am looking for a UI designer tool for android. I have tried many sites, but cannot find anything useful.

Some designer tools are only for wire-framing 
e.g. http://www.fluidui.com 
But they do not give me an XML layout source.

I know about: 
http://www.droiddraw.org/
but this tool is very old and it uses AbsoluteLayout, which is deprecated.

Eclipse UI designer tool is hard to use in my opinion. 
Button drag and drop for elements do not work correctly. I like Visual Studio's Form Designer, I think it is the best designer tool for C#. Especially for positioning - drag anything you want and drop where you want, it is very easy and useful.

Is there any good designer tool for Android like Visual Studio's Form Designer?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the eclipse editor, but if you don't like that the other big one is in IntelliJ IDEA and the new Android Studio.  Android Studio is beta and based on IntelliJ, but looks more friendly.

IntelliJ IDEA: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html
Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html